# camera animation with known distance between frames

Tags: animation, camera

I'm trying to simulate a camera fixed on car which is moving along a straight path. I've been trying doing this using a curve path. The problem is that I need to know/specify exactly the distance the car/camera travelled between frames. Is there a direct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set the Scene units to Metric or Imperial (or metric, seriously). Then you would take your path length (ie. 50m) divided by the frames elapsed (ie. 100f) to get the camera velocity (ie. 50m/100f = 0.5m/f). Then you know that the camera travels 0.5m for every elapsed frame. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I figured as much, but I don't get how to relate this to the camera's frame rate. I basically need an image sequence in which every image has been "photographed" at a certain distance from the previous one.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. That's all the info I need actually.